# Problem connecting to a Exchange 2007 server in PHP5 with imap_open

Tags: php, exchange-server-2007, imap-open

When im trying to connect to an Exchange 2007 server over IMAP in PHP5 I get the following error message.

```
Kerberos error: No credentials cache found (try running kinit) for smtp.domain01.net
```

I was wondering if somebody found a way around this issue?

Related info: 
http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33500

Comment: I had this problem last month, even when dealing with some exchange people we ended up connecting to another server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just stumbled upon this question and thought I'd answer this one since no one else has. The following page gives a very direct and accurate answer on how to solve the problem: http://forums.kayako.com/threads/fix-kerberos-error-on-email-parser.29626/

Basically whats happening here (according to http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvradmin/thread/43aef3d6-3e91-4e41-a788-ae073393ad37/) is that Microsoft Exchange 2007 broadcasts malformed Kerberos tokens, which causes the PHP IMAP driver to kill the stream. Some other sources claim that this is [a PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33500) either way the solution in summary entails you to re-compile the PHP-IMAP extension with Kerberos disabled. This will force PHP IMAP to use Plain text authentication and will fix your problem.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange does have the IMAP protocol enabled by default. Even when it does, the Exchange implementation of IMAP may or may not really be IMAP. That said, [this Technet thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrtransport/thread/1a84a06a-f1c8-40b4-ace8-1e264f218aa1) may apply to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one, but after getting this problem a couple of times recently after years of no issues, something else was the cause for us. Turns out the Exchange server just needed the IMAP service restarted!

The consensus on a lot of sites was the same as above answers, but I really didn't want to go down the path of recompiling PHP. for me this issue didn't seem to have anything to do with Kerberos or PHP issues, just a simple authentication problem.  Possibly the service needed a restart as it was sending malformed tokens...Hopefully someone else will find this helpful.

Comment: More often than not you don't own the server since it belongs to a big service provider.